# How to push new elements in an array as they increase in number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures

I have a gird with a few nodes. As I move my mouse on the gird, the values of `row` and `col` change.

For example:

```
  const handleMouseEnter = (row, col) => {
    console.log(row, col);
  };
```

this code returns this on the console:

[image]

These are the coordinates.

---

The question is: How do I store these values in an array as they grow? I tried to do it with the push function like this:

```
  const handleMouseEnter = (row, col) => {
    const coordinatesVisited = [];
    coordinatesVisited.push(row, col);

    console.log(coordinatesVisited);
  };
```

but it just returns me this:

[image]

I want all these arrays in one single array at the end. The grid is small so performance issues won't be any problem. The array can be overwritten again and again.

EDIT:
With this code, 1-2  values are logged only while the log statement is inside the function but nothing stays.

```
  const coordinatesVisited = [];
  const handleMouseEnter = (row, col) => {

    coordinatesVisited.push([row, col]);

  };
  console.log(coordinatesVisited);
```

Outside of the function, it is still an empty array.

This is probably a very simple question but right now I can't think of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each time const declare new array variable. So you need to declare array on before function call like global variable

```
 const coordinatesVisited = []; // declare as global
 const handleMouseEnter = (row, col) => {
    coordinatesVisited.push(row, col);
    console.log(coordinatesVisited);
  };
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried that too. But that doesn't work. It only contains 1-2 values only inside that function. Outside, it is again empty. I want to use that on a global level.

Comment: Ya, This worked now. I needed to declare that array outside that component.